# Azure VM stats - Network In/Out - what are the measurements?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, monitor, metrics

I feel perturbed, but I don't understand the measurement Azure uses for Network In/Out and a few other things.

On Azure portal -> my VM -> Metrics -> [Host] Network In/Out, it says that it is measured in bytes, but then it also draws graph over time. [image: Azure VM Monitoring] If it were plain, bytes, it should be cumulative and therefore grow indefinitely, but it isn't, therefore I am inclined to believe it is measured per second or something like that. But Azure docs claim that it is bytes and not bytes per second ([link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftcomputevirtualmachines))

[image]

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am inclined to believe the data is in bytes per minute.  At least for mine it appears that way.  I set my graph for a 10 minute interval.  Taking the mouse off the graph the total bytes show at the bottom.  Hovering over the individual sample points (10 in total) they average between 31-34MB each.  Adding them up you get close to the total for the graph interval 326MB.  10*32.5 is very close to the this total leading me to believe that each interval on the graph is a sum of the individual interval (1 minute).  That is what I am seeing anyway.  Terrible documentation from Microsoft.  Why not just specify this in the (i) hover point on the individual graph? 
@eddyP23 - if you add up all your points in your graph it appears you would come to the same conclusion.  Each point is a sum of the interval (1 minute).  I am not sure how else to read this.
If it were bytes per second the data total for the complete interval would be vastly larger.  [10 minute interval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERC9J.png)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay.

> therefore I am inclined to believe it is measured per second or
>   something like that. But Azure docs claim that it is bytes and not
>   bytes per second

You can find the **Network In** here:

[image]

The Network In (bytes per second) used for monitor your VM's performance.

Comment: So does your graph show MBs of network per second? And the box at the bottom shows the aggregate for the whole period? `Network (total)` does not say anything about seconds/minutes/hour/whatever and that is what I find confusing

Comment: @eddyP23 in my screenshot, the time is one day, sum of network in.