# High Azure Network Usage In/Out

Tags: azure, network-traffic

I have an Azure VM running (Win) where the Scheduler regularly calls a VBS script to load a small data set, retrieved from a web site API, into a SQL database table. Now, when I see the Network-In and -Out chart on my Azure Portal Dashboard there seems ridiculously high traffic going on, like GBs of data flowing in and out for no obvious reason. My VBS only loads small KB amounts per day - where is all that traffic [Azure Dashboard Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSxLe.jpg) coming from?

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, you properly set the **Time range** as **Last 30 days** in your Metrics Chart. If you take the mouse off the graph, the **total bytes** show at the bottom. This reflects the total incoming or outgoing network traffic received all the interface on the machine in the last few days. You could set the time range to one day.

[image]

Generally, we use the network in or out metric monitor **network performance** on the VM. Refer to the network metric in the [article](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-monitor-microsoft-azure-vms/).

Comment: Hi Nancy, I did as you proposed; pls see the 12hrs screenshot. However, the running VBS script by no means could have transferred 120MB in these 12 hrs (120KB is more likely). Also, i cannot explain the recurring spikes in both screenshots since the vbs is repeatedly doing the very same job. Any idea what could be sending such amounts of data around at any time looked at? Is it the VM's Windows OS or Azure? Anyone having the same experience? (Hmm, how do I insert the screenshot here...)

Comment: Since Azure VM will keep online in the Azure backend network, there are some Agent and services running, those will consume network traffic. Also, the sum of network in and out collects the number of bytes received on all network interfaces by the Virtual Machine. You will see the individual sample points in a different Time granularity. If you set the time interval longer, you might not see the spikes. You could see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542570/azure-vm-stats-network-in-out-what-are-the-measurements).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help. At least it seems that I don't have to worry about those unidentified GBs going in and out of my Azure VM. Hopefully they won't charge me for these with the question in mind whether these volumes are counted towards the included traffic...

Comment: You could get the [pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/#virtual-network0b5a91e8-f9ca-4651-9d16-d1cb394c6ed2) to know which resources will be almost charged.

Comment: Yes, in fact my concerns are that I don't believe at the moment that maintaining a VM in Azure eats up 7-8 GBs of traffic every 30 days. Also, whether that this traffic counts into my included traffic. Is there an official Azure statement on this? Further, I wonder why there are apparently no other ppl concerned here on SO, or able to help on this question about what excactly is going on. Maybe my Azure account is hacked; me not seeing this is no real proof that I am not. I don't really have my question answered, but do appreciate your kind help!

Comment: If you want to see the network traffic, you could run a network monitor tool like `Wireshark`or `network monitor` to capture the data packets. Not only your scripts traffic, but there will also be other network connection go through a network interface. Actually, if you have pay-as-you-go billing. Azure VM is charged by storage account, size. VNet is free of charge. Every subscription is allowed to create up to 50 virtual networks across all regions.https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-network/

Comment: Thanks again for your input. I know about Wireshark etc but have no time to digging into it, to set it up, and record and analyse IP packets. That why I asked my question rather generically about the plausibility of GB-size traffic on a VM with intentionally low user-application traffiic. Hence, I'd like to keep my question open/

Answer (score 1):

My conclusion / answer is now the the LRS is responsible for the traffic. Thanks also for your help!